# Fecth Single Data Array From Parent Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have created 2 table

TABLE products

```
------------------------------
| ID | name    | duration|
------------------------------
| 1  | box     |   10    |
| 2  | plastic |   20    |
------------------------------
```

and TABLE productSub

```
-------------------------------------------------
| ID | type    | min_order | max_order | parent |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | paper S |    1      |    10     |    1   |
| 2  | paper L |    11     |    50     |    1   |
| 3  | wood S  |    1      |    20     |    2   |
| 4  | wood L  |    21     |    50     |    2   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

in database productSub **parent** means the ID of database products, I already success show the all data with sub data in php code. The data display with input radio button to choose which data they want to order.

```
<form method="post" name="productform">
   <?php foreach($allproducts as $key => $products):?>
   <h4 class="title">
        <input type="radio" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $products['id'];?>" checked="">
        <?php echo $products['name'].'  <small>'.$products['duration'].'</small>';?>
   </h4>
   <?php $allproductsparent = getAllProductsParent($products['id']); foreach($allproductsparent as $value):?>
   <table class="table"><tr>
       <th scope="row"><?php echo $value['type'];?></th>
       <td><?php echo $value['min_order'].' ~ '.$value['max_order'];?></td>
   </tr></table>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <input type="text" id="order" class="form-control" name="order" placeholder="Total Order" required>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submit it will POST a data to my php page and give me the data form.

What I get after submitting data is two array consist of productSub.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Paper S
            [min_order] => 1
            [max_order] => 10
            [duration] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Paper L
            [min_order] => 11
            [max_order] => 50
            [duration] => 10
        )

)
```

The question is how to filter data based on **Total Order** submit. And data should be between one of productSub min order and max order, then show only 1 productSub that match criteria.
Thanks

=====================================================================

For you additional info, I've made this PDO to show the submitted data

```
function getProductById($id){
    $res_arr = [];
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ps.*,p.* FROM productsub ps INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = ps.parent WHERE ps.parent = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($res = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $res_arr[]= $res;
    }
    return $res_arr;
}
```

And show it like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(getProductById($_POST['p_id']));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Do you mean databases or tables?

Comment: I mean show the tables data based on Total Order input, because the min_order and max_order have different value between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer

using foreach in my php and filter some data will give me a exactly data that What I want from submitted form.

Here is the code.

```
    foreach($productid as $product){
        if($_POST['order'] >= $product['min_order'] && $_POST['order'] <= $product['max_order']){
            echo $product['name'].' because the order was '.$_POST['order'];
        }
    }
```

And will show the data like this

> paper 1 because the order was 10

Thanks for all

Comment: Why do you use `$_POST['order']` in one part and `$_POST['amount']` in another?

Comment: I have one more question, How if the client choose the second products and choose the total order < from minimum order? It will give them a null response? how to make if they choose total order < than minimum order it will be the minimal order